# "Hard" exercises on Linear Algebra and Analytic Geometry

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

I started lecturing this subject called "Linear Algebra and Analytic Geometry" and in the second day of class I was approached by an undergrad student, asking for referenced that would contain "hard" exercises. I understand that the ones on the book I'm mostly following might seem pretty basic, since they aim for more "average" students (by the way, this is in Brazil).

I checked on this student's profile and noticed that she has actually received some medals on Brazil's Olympiads of Mathematics for teenagers. I do not want to lose this student to get bored with her first experience with University-level Mathematics (her graduation subject is Computer Science), and since she said she'd have no problem with an english or spanish textbook, I would like to ask my fellow Stackers for textbooks that contain above-average exercises on Linear Algebra and Analytic Geometry. "Theoretical" exercises, as in "show this identity" or "proof this result" are more into what I'm expecting.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a first course in linear algebra? How much experience do you think this student is likely to have with the material? There are probably plenty of "hard" exercises for which a beginning student wouldn't know the meaning of the terms involved.

Comment: I'm not sure about her background. It is her first course in Linear Algebra, yes, but I wouldn't be surprised if she had already studied some of the things we'll see along the semester.

Comment: You might consider the Springer book "Berkeley Problems in Mathematics"; the book is a collection of problems from Berkeley postgraduate qualifying exams, organised according to subject - in particular, there is a linear algebra section. I have no idea how many of the problems she'll be able to do right now, but at least she should be able to attempt some of them during the course.

Comment: Matrix Analysis by Horn has a lot to chew on which is considerably beyond some of the elementary texts; http://ebooks.cambridge.org/ebook.jsf?bid=CBO9780511810817 Also, you might look at a functional analysis text like Royden for some nice problems. Another idea, and an absolute art, is Morton Curtis's Abstract Linear Algebra. It would guide her through the proof of Hurwitz' theorem among other things. Roman is also a higher-level text which may be of use to you. But, I would guess http://www.amazon.com/Linear-Algebra-A-Geometric-Approach/dp/071674337X Shifrin's text is what you want.